# Why is this returning a string instead of a dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I'm using Python 3.6 to parse a JSON file that consists of a bunch of nested dictionaries. As I'm looping through the JSON I'm expecting that my inner loop should return a dictionary, but Python tells me it's a string and I have no idea why.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the JSON file I'm parsing:

```
"SaveDataList": [
  {
    "PartyData": {
      "ResourceInventory": {
        "resources": {
          "Herbs": {
            "resourceID": "Herbs",
            "resourceType": "Herbs",
            "amount": 19,
            "amountReserved": 0
          }
```

There are more items under "resources", but you get the idea.
Here is my code to parse the JSON:

```
for x in SaveJSON["SaveDataList"]:
  if "SaveGame.GlobalData" in x["$type"]:
    for y in x["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"]:
      print(y,": ",y["amount"],sep='')
```

The error I get when I do this is "TypeError: string indices must be integers". When I do `type(y)` it returns `<class 'str'>`. When I do `type(x)` it returns `<class 'dict'>`. I don't understand why. It seems to me that y should return the "Herbs" dictionary object.

So really my question is, how can I get each dictionary object under "resources"? Thank you.

Comment: What does y itself print as?

Comment: `print(y)` displays Herbs

Comment: I'm kind of stumped! Can you print `x["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]`. Also I'm not familiar with this SaveJSON function.

Comment: If there are multiple entries in `"resources"`, `for x in SaveJSON["SaveDataList"]:
    print(x["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"])` seems to work for me.

Comment: Yes I can. I can even print `x["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"]["Herbs"]["amount"]`. But what I want is an object that represents each dictionary under "resources" so I don't have to hardcode every print. SaveJSON isn't a function, it's just the output of `json.load` on a JSON file.

Comment: @downshift Yeah that works but does not return the dictionary object under "resources".

Comment: `print(type(x["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"]))` returns `<type 'dict'>`, seems like they *are* dictionary objects

Comment: Yeah, I just need a handle to the dictionary object :)

Comment: So you want to get at the dictionary items of each `'resource'`? For the `'amount'` item, try `for item in SaveJSON["SaveDataList"][0]["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"]:
    print(SaveJSON["SaveDataList"][0]["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"][item]['amount'])`

Comment: That will work for that one very specific thing, but I don't want to have to hardcode every print.

Comment: ok, couldn't you assign the key to a variable, say `resources = SaveJSON["SaveDataList"][0]["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"]`, then do `[print [resources[item]['amount'] for item in resources]`? gives me `[19, 22]`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to *initialize dictionary by "{ }"* and you have not actually defined y as the dictionary. For python that "y" in the loop is simply an element in the stuff defined after that.

In the beginning **create an empty dictionary** and then update it with new data.

```
y = {}

for x in SaveJSON["SaveDataList"]:
  if "SaveGame.GlobalData" in x["$type"]:
    for i in x["PartyData"]["ResourceInventory"]["resources"]:
      print( y.update(i) )
```

I guess it should solve the problem, now type(y) would return "dictionary" type

Comment: But using strings to index works all the way up to resources, why's that? This seems like it'd be a sold workaround, but it doesn't help us understand why this is occurring.

Comment: This gives me `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`. Probably because i is a string not a tuple so it can't update a dictionary.